# Could the animorphs change into anything with DNA?

Tags: animorphs, morphing

Since all living things have cells, could it be possible for someone with the morphing ability be able to change into a bacteria, or even a plant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ability to morph is granted by the [Escafil Device](http://animorphs.wikia.com/wiki/Escafil_device) which:

> When touched, it gives the user the permanent ability to acquire DNA from live animals and change ("morph") into the animal.

So the morphing power is normally limited to animals. However in [*The Return*](http://animorphs.wikia.com/wiki/The_Return), Rachel was able to morph into a walking venus flytrap and a gigantic version of herself with "mechanical claws" and superhuman strength. These morphs are not permanently available and Rachel only got the chance because Crayak manipulated the world to show her what she could become with his help. Since she refuses to do as Crayak asks, Rachel cannot actually morph into these things.

Answer (score 7):

The exact mechanics of the Escafil Device (morphing cube) are unknown - however, going by what is told in the book, the user has to acquire DNA from a living being. There is no chemical difference between plants and animals as far as DNA goes, but there may be an in-world limitation based around the main difference between plants/bacteria and animals: The lack of a nervous system. 
Since the morpher's and morph's instinctual mind both exist within the morphed animal, to the point where sometimes the morpher cannot control the morph (Elfangor and Arbron as Taxxons in The Andalite Chronicles come to mind), it's not a far leap to make that the morpher can only morph into something that has a place for their mind to exist.

That's just a theory on my part, though, and as far as the books go, it is never explicitly stated that the morphing power does not extend to plants or bacteria. It may indeed be possible, and the only reason that nobody does it is simply because nobody wants to be a plant or bacteria.

Comment: I might want to be a bacteria for a time if I intended to clone myself.

Comment: They did that in the books when Rachel was a star fish and it was... complicated. But hey, your mileage may vary!

Comment: If I remember correctly, one of them wondered about morphing into plants after they lost control of a hive-mind morph (an ant, I think).  I can't remember which character's POV it was, but I believe they were afraid to even attempt it because of the possibility of being trapped in a morph by becoming something incapable of thought.

Answer (score 2):

### They can change into bacteria (in theory) but not plants.

**Bacteria**

> **Can the Animorphs morph germs?**
>
> ***KAA:*** *In theory, yes. But there's no way to acquire one.*
> <sub>[Scholastic.com - "According to K.A." October 1998](http://web.archive.org/web/20000919005039/http://www.scholastic.com:80/animorphs/ka9810.htm)</sub>
>
> **Can the animorphs morph single cell creatures? If so, why didn't they when they morph anything. Because germs are all over us.**
>
> ***KAA:*** *You know, I've thought of this from time to time. The problem I have is how to "acquire" a germ. How do you know you're touching a particular germ? How do you focus on acquiring something you can't even see? If you figure it out, let me know.*
> <sub>[Scholastic.com - "According to K.A." October 1998](http://web.archive.org/web/20000919005039/http://www.scholastic.com:80/animorphs/ka9810.htm)</sub>
>
> **When they morph, do they also morph the bacteria in the animals?**
>
> ***KAA:*** *Actually, no. They would acquire only the one DNA type. Although, it's an interesting question. Lots of bacteria are useful and even necessary. I understand that humans have bacteria that are necessary for proper digestion. Leading to the question of whether an Andalite morphing a human without benefit of his bacteria might not have digestive problems. Does Ax in human morph suffer from more than the usual amount of flatulence? This is the sort of profound question we should be addressing, rather than wasting time on the meaning of life.*
> <sub>[Scholastic.com - "According to K.A." December 1998](http://web.archive.org/web/20000919005030/http://www.scholastic.com:80/animorphs/ka9812.htm)</sub>
>
> **I really enjoy your books, they are perfect for my busy schedule. (...) I remember you wondering how the Animorphs could morph bacteria. Well, if they ever wanted to, they could always press their fingers in agar in a petri dish. Within a couple days, colonies would form that they could touch.**
>
> ***KAA:*** *You say you have a busy schedule and yet you found the time to consider the Truly Important Issue of morphing bacteria. Hmmm.*
> <sub>[Scholastic.com - "According to K.A." January 1999](http://web.archive.org/web/20000919005025/http://www.scholastic.com:80/animorphs/ka9901.htm)</sub>

**Plants**

> **Can Animorphs morph plants?**
>
> ***KAA:*** *No. What, you want Jake to morph a Brussels sprout and give Visser Three gas?*
> <sub>[Scholastic.com - "According to K.A." October 1998](http://web.archive.org/web/20000919005039/http://www.scholastic.com:80/animorphs/ka9810.htm)</sub>