# What can Animorphs become?

Tags: animorphs

Is it possible for an Animorph to become Gojira or another Kaiju\Titan? Also, is it possible for them to become a Cybertronian? I just wanted to know if there are limits based on size or biology. I'm asking this for a fanfic I plan on writing, I just want to be lore accurate it is about how the Yeerks activities on earth attracted the attention of Gojira and the Autobots.

Comment: If you haven't visited the [tour], please do so. It will tell you how to accept answers. It also establishes out policy requiring questions and answers being about specific canon.

Comment: Please refrain from editing additional questions, you are free to ask more questions on this site. But I recommend looking around at how other questions have been written, and following the links @FuzzyBoots has provided.

Comment: also could a yeerk infest a kaiju or cybertronian i was thinking of having a yeerk infest a kaiju or cybertronian

Comment: @elijah sanch That sounds like another good question, although I don't know how canonical of an answer exists.

Comment: aparently the animorphs dont turn into scentient creatures does gojira aply to that

Comment: @ElijahSanch I would encourage you to ask a [new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for your new questions

Comment: @AncientSwordRage i cant

Comment: @ElijahSanch sometimes the website blocks asking questions until you have positively received questions or a certain amount of time has passed. It looks like that's happened so you'll need to wait until the block is lifted

Comment: Also does this answer your question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105838/could-the-animorphs-change-into-anything-with-dna

Comment: @ElijahSanch The avoidance on turning into sentient creatures was an ethical issue, not a technical one. They do turn into specific humans a few times (and a running theme of the series is that the boundary between humans=sentient animals=not-sentient is not as clear as we often think)

Comment: “Do the Animorphs become other things besides animals?”Yes: traumatized.

Answer (score 5):

With the caveat that this is user-edited, [the rules](https://animorphs.fandom.com/wiki/Morphing)

> 1. You can't change directly from one morph to another without first returning to your natural body.
>    2. You have to acquire DNA directly from an animal. You can't acquire it from another morph.
>    3. You can't stay in morph for more than two hours at a time, because if you do, you stay permanently.

Nothing explicitly prohibits *kaiju* size as long as the DNA can be acquired, although the rules for large amount of Zero Space matter are undefined. Cybertronians [lack DNA, although they have an equivalent](https://transformers.fandom.com/wiki/Reproduction), so they're probably not a match. You might be able to get DNA of the transformed animals from the Cybertronians in [*Beast Wars*](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/DNA), but it would not be the robotic part.

Comment: thanks for the info